# Select the second XML element in an array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am getting via simpleXML, the part of it here:

```
...

<channel id="Polo TV">
    <display-name lang="pl">Polo TV</display-name>
    <icon src="http://m-tvguide.pl/ikony/polo.png" />
    <url>http://www.programtv.interia.pl</url>
  </channel>
  <programme start="20141030005500 +0100" stop="20141030015000 +0100" channel="TVP 1">
    <title lang="pl">Po prostu</title>
    <sub-title lang="pl">http://i.iplsc.com/-/0003K96AEV7D81JK-C0.jpg</sub-title>

    ...

    <category lang="pl">Informacja</category>
    <category lang="pl">Program Tomasza Sekielskiego</category>
  </programme>
  <programme start="20141030015000 +0100" stop="20141030033500 +0100" channel="TVP 1">
    <title lang="pl">Dorwać małego</title>

...
```

more: http://wklej.to/2zmFZ . 
My php script:

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

$channels = array();
foreach ($xml->channel as $c) {
    $channels[ $c['id']->__toString() ] = $c->{'display-name'}->__toString();
}

$time = date( "YmdHi" );

foreach($xml->xpath( 'programme[@channel="TVP"]' ) as $item) {
    $start = substr( (string)$item["start"], 0, -8);
    $end   = substr( (string)$item["stop"], 0, -8);
    if ($time > $start && $time < $end) {
    echo "<b><font size='3'>$item->title </font></b><br>";
        echo "<u><b>Gatunek:</b></u> ".$item->{'category'}. "<br>";
        echo "<u><b>Start:</b></u> " .date("G:i", strtotime($start)) . '<br>';
        echo "<u><b>Koniec:</b></u> " .date("G:i", strtotime($end)) . '<br>';
        echo "<u><b>Kanał:</b></u> ".$channels[ $item["channel"]->__toString() ]. "<br>";     
        echo "<u><b>Opis:</b></u> ".$item->desc. "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

As it can be seen in xml file there are always two `<category>` directives provided. I want to get the second one instead of the first, as it is doing now.

Comment: What do you mean by "two directives"?

Comment: I mean this:     <category lang="pl">Filmy</category>
    <category lang="pl">Komedia Sensacyjna</category>. In this case i would like to get "Komedia Sensacyjna" instead of "Filmy". But "filmy" will appear as a category, because it is first in the row.

Comment: And the same with other categories, e.g. `<category lang="pl">Seriale</category><category lang="pl">Serial Sensacyjny</category>` and `<category lang="pl">Informacja</category><category lang="pl">Program Tomasza Sekielskiego</category>`? You always want the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of elements, you can access them as you would elements in a standard PHP array, using a numeric subscript. It is best to check if the element is set first, though:

```
foreach($xml->xpath( 'programme[@channel="TVP"]' ) as $item) {
    // code here...
    # check whether the 'category' element is present
    if (isset($item->category)) {
        echo "<u><b>Gatunek:</b></u> ";
        # check if there are two category items; if so, print the second
        if (isset($item->category[1])) {
            echo $item->category[1] . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo $item->category . "<br>";
        }
    }
    // more code here...
}
```

Comment: For readability, it might be better to write the default case as `->category[0]` instead of `->category`, since it makes the two cases look symmetrical; the result is always the same with either notation.

Answer (score 1):

Take the second category (they are zero-indexed) and if it does not exists, take the first one:

```
$item->category[1] ?: $item->category;
```

Comment: For readability, it might be better to write the default case as `->category[0]` instead of `->category`, since it makes the two cases look symmetrical; the result is always the same with either notation.